# Why aren't serial upvoting of questions reversed

Tags: discussion, badges, voting

Serial upvoting of a single user's questions I have little doubt are detectable and reversed...

But what about dumping the daily allotment of 40 votes in a short amount of time on many questions from many users, a method that I should add, can earn someone 4 different participation badges (including a gold one).

Why isn't there flood protection on voting, just like on commenting? Are those voting related badges helpful (Suffrage, Vox Populi, Civic Duty, Electorate) in the way they are currently designed?

Answer (score 9):

They are reversed, just after a period of maximum 24 hours. The serial upvoting detection script is a heavy one and is run daily.

If you find such a case that is not reversed, let the moderators know in a custom flag.

Answer (score 6):

Well, that's *why* you only get 40 per day - before that restriction was put in place, folks were abusing it.

Occasionally, we do encounter someone doing something crazy with their 40/day, but generally-speaking votes are the voter's to do with as he wishes - even if that means squandering them.